# What are the steps to go from SimpleSnitch to GossipingPropertyFileSnitch in a live cassandra cluster?

Tags: cassandra

Besides making sure the datacenter name is the same in the cassandra-rackdc.properties file and the one originally created (defaults to **datacenter1**), what else do I have to take into account?

Can I do a rolling restart or should I kill the entire cluster and then startup one at a time?

Comment: i think rolling restart will be enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I did it and it worked.

Just make sure your configuration is the same as created by default, and do a rolling restart.